# AngularJS ng-view returns Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

> I want to integrate Spring boot, thymeleaf template, and angularjs. When I
>   add  to my index.html template it gives me Whitelabel error 
>   page. And I dont know what's causing the errror.
>
> Here is my index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http:/www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Boot Application</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/bootstrap.css}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#!loginbutton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
            app.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when("/loginbutton", {templateUrl: "login.html"});
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> My controller

```
    package com.spring.springbootapplication.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class springbootapplicationController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcomeController(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("welcome", "Spring boot application");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loginbutton")
    public String loginController() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

> Well Im just playing around with angularjs and spring boot.

Comment: it's not enough. give me ur controller method too

Comment: and i think, the `<script>` tag is broken.

Comment: and in with which url did u try to load the page?

Comment: where did u store the `index.html`?

Comment: well, im trying to load the login.html which was in the same folder with index.html

Comment: i would write an answer, and i hope u take my advises

Comment: I stored it in the src/main/resources/templates. both index.html and login.html are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, using thymleaf and angular at the same time is very weird. Both of them are frontend technologies, but the use of them are different.

if u want to use thymeleaf, then u have to add model, but in ur example no need to model. But, if u want to use Angular u need to make your BackEnd with REST.

**So,First remove all angular stuff**

It seems that, u are using maven, and set the index html in proper folder in resources. So, if ur app is run on port 8080 then you only need to go to go to

`localhost:8080/` and then it should show up

Comment: Oh, so that's how. But in any case, would it be possible to add angular? The reason I added angular was to make my web app a single page application.

Comment: i never heard someone get both angular, and thymeleaf to work at the same time. For me, it is not possible, and does not make sense.And thanks for acceptance

Comment: Okay. Thanks. :)